# Stack Overflow Exploit in C

Tags: c, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, exploit

The question is actually about stack overflows in C. 
I have an assigment that I can not get done for the life of me, I've looked at everything in the gdb and I just cant figure it.

The question is the following:

```
int i,n;

void confused()
{
    printf("who called me");
    exit(0);
}

void shell_call(char *c)
{
    printf(" ***Now calling \"%s\" shell command *** \n",c);
    system(c);
    exit(0);
}

void victim_func()
{
    int a[4];
    printf("[8]:%x\n", &a[8]);
    printf("Enter n: "); scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter %d HEX Values \n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%x",&a[i]);
    printf("Done reading junk numbers\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("ls=736c --- ps = 7370 --- cal = 6c6163\n");
    printf("location of confused %x \n", confused);
    printf("location of shell_call %x \n", shell_call);
    victim_func();
    printf("Done, thank you\n");

}
```

Ok, so I managed to get the first question correctly, which is to arbitrarily call one of the two functions not explicitly called in the main path. By the way, this has to be done while running the program without any modifications.
I did this by running the program, setting `N` to `7`, which gets me to the Function Pointer of the `victim_func` frame, I write `a[7]` with the memory address of confused or `shell_call`, and it works. (I have a 64 bit machine, thats why I have to get it to 7, since the EBI pointer is 2 ints wide, instead of 1)

My question is the following, how could I control which argument gets passed to the `shell_code` funcion? ie. how do I write a `string` to `char* c`.
The whole point is executing unix commands like **ps** etc, by running only the program.

I figured writing the EBI pointer with the hex representation of **ps** and setting the arg list of `shell_call` to that, but that didn't work. I also tried inputing `argsv` arguments and setting the arg list of `shell_call` to the `arg_list` of main, but didn't work either.

I think the second version should work, but I believe I'm not setting the arg list of the new stack frame correctly ( I did it by writing `a[8]` to `0`, since its the first part of the function pointer, and writing `a[9]=736c` and `a[10]=0000`, but its probably not right since those are the parameters of `victim_func`. So how do I access the parameters of `shell_call`?

Comment: note that this is a _buffer_ overflow, not a _stack_ overflow.

Comment: @Greg Rogers  actually yes,  this is a stack overflow.  In fact the heap isn't used in this application.

Comment: @Rook: The buffer is on the stack. But the buffer overflow is the vulnerability. A stack overflow isn't exploitable -- otherwise every XML parser on earth would be vulnerable ;)

Comment: @Rook: Stack overflow means exhausting the stack space, for example with an infinite recursion, and is not exploitable. What you have here is a buffer overflow in the stack. It's named similarly, but a whole different beast. :)

Answer (score 8):

I probably shouldn't do your homework for you.  But the basically:

You need to get a character buffer somewhere in memory to store the string you want to execute.  Obviously, you can do this the same way you are getting the other functions called (i.e. you put the text on the stack as well).  After you have that written, you need to write a pointer to it on to the stack in the location that the shell_code function expects to find its arguments.

The best way to figure this out without me doing *all* of the work for you is to write down your stack/memory contents on a piece of paper/whiteboard.  Write down how it would look if you called shell_code normally from inside the program.  Then write down what the stack looks like inside victum_func and figure out which things to change to get it to look like it would look "naturally" (of course keeping in mind some things are "don't cares" like the return address).

That's all the charity you're gonna get from me today! :-P

Answer (score 2):

SoapBox already did a great job of leading you in the right direction.

For more information;
http://www.skullsecurity.org/wiki/index.php/Example_4

Answer (score 1):

You need to manipulate the stack-frame of the caller (`main()`), and arrange it in such a way that returning to `shell_call()` from the epilog of the overflowed `victim_func()` the latter could find a settled stack as it was been called by the main.

In doing so you probably have to mangle the frame-pointer in the stackframe of the victim, that will be restored in %ebp by means of `leave`.

Comment: Wow I have exploited buffer overflows and I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @Rook Looks like @Nicola used one of those fancy Markov chain text generator thingies. :P