# Write a program to exploit the stack overflow vulnerability of the program and obtain a shell on Linux

Tags: c, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Exploit in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286090/stack-overflow-exploit-in-c)

I need to write a program to exploit the stack overflow vulnerability of the following program. I have never done anything of this sort. I understand how it works in theory both the stack and the overflow. But I'm clueless about the implementation in C. Please help me with this. I just need a clear understanding of the steps to be taken in order to overflow the stack and generate the shell code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int myprint(char* argv1)
{
    printf("%s", argv1);
}
void foo(char* argv1, char* argv2) 
{
    int (*fptr)(char*) = myprint;
    char buf[12];
    strcpy(buf, argv1);
    fptr(argv2);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    if (argc < 3) 
    {
            printf("error\n");
            return;
    }

    foo(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your ability to exploit this code, is the following two lines:

```
char buf[12];
strcpy(buf, argv1);
```

You can see here that you have a buffer called `buf` of size `12` bytes, which has limited space.  Now on the next line, you're taking `argv1` and you're copying it into `buf` without checking that the size of `argv1` is smaller than `buf`.

This means that this **unchecked** version of `strcpy` allows you to write past the end of `buf` and then potentially overwrite the return address of the stackframe of this function.

At the end of a stackframe just before the function returns you'll normally find in the assembler as statement like `ret` in assembler (can be different in different types of assembler, I'm assuming x86 here), which essentially jumps back to the caller, using the address stored on the stack (normally, depending on calling-convention, stored before this function was called).

You could then overwrite that address with something that points to some shellcode you've placed in some free space that will execute and open a shell.

Here is a section on [calling-convention](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) in X86 assembler that explains what happens when you call a function, and how the prologue and epilogue are done.